# Fetch the specific column value from Datatable when user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, arrays

I have a datatable populated with `aaData` which is depicting the task created by users. Now, there is an `action` column in datatable which has two or three action buttons or logos like pdf - to view the user guide of that task, browse- link for the source code of the task and one is **contributors** logo which onclick should display the contributors for that particular task.

The `aaData` is of the following format which is populating the table

```
"aaData": [
    [
        "JSAG Home Page",
        "JSAG Home page contains information about various POCs done",
        "05/12/2012",
        [
                {
                   "displayValue":"Browse",
                   "link":"http://myTask.com/home",
                   "displayIcon" : "browselogo"
                },
                {   
                    "displayValue":"Source Code",
                    "link":"svn/HomePage/trunk/",
                    "displayIcon" : "svnlogo"
                },
                {   
                   "displayValue":"Audience Overview",
                    "link":"svn/Documents/Audience Overview.pdf",
                    "displayIcon" : "pdflogo"
               },
                 {  
                    "displayValue":"Contributors: ABC,XYZ",
                    "link":"#",
                    "displayIcon" : "people"
             }

        ],

    ],
    [
        "Backlog",
        "Backlog Forum application is designed to provide a platform for different groups to maintain backlog task items. ",
        "25/08/2012",
        [
            {   
                "displayValue":"Browse",
                "link":"http://mytask.com/BacklogApp",
                "displayIcon" : "browselogo"
            },
            {   
            "displayValue":"Source Code",
                "link":"svn/trunk/webapp-project/",
                "displayIcon" : "svnlogo"
            },
            {   
            "displayValue":"Contributors: ABC",
                "link":"#",
                "displayIcon" : "people"
            }
        ],

    ]
  ]
```

This format is for all datatables   and contributors logo is there in all. What i wanted was, when user clicks the **contributors** icon, he should be able to see those contributors `"ABC, XYZ, PQR"`.

I thought of fetching the action column data and then `$each()` the `contributors` array but i am not able to proceed with it.

How can i achieve this thing? How can i pick up the column value `onclick` because each datatable is being populated dynamically.
Please help.

Below is the code to populate a contributors div

```
$(document).on('click', '#contributor', function(contributors){
        $.each(contributors, function(i, data) {
            var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ data+ "</h3></li>";
            $("#contributors_div").append(ul_data);
        });
   }
    $('#contributors_div').show();
   });
```

How do i get`recentActdata` as my contributors JSON array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to be similar to this, provided you are declaring you datatable in the variable oTable

```
$(document).on('click', '#contributor', function(){
      var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this) );
      console.log(aPos);
      //if aPos returns an array in console, use first val at pos zero to get row data
      var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);
      console.log(aData);
      // inspect your returned object, then tailor your $.each iteration
            $.each( aData["contributors"], function(i, data) {
                var ul_data = "<li><h3>"+ data+ "</h3></li>";
                $("#contributors_div").append(ul_data);
            });
       }
        $('#contributors_div').show();
       });
```

Comment: thats the point no. How am i going to get that datatable on an icon click?

Comment: actually, the JSON format has been modified. Could you please update your code accordingly. I just need to pick `"displayValue":"Contributors: ABC,XYZ",`. I have `oTable` data as well

Comment: also with this code i am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined `  in `jquery.datatables.js` file

Comment: Can you post your datatables initialization? Also what do the console.logs show?

Comment: Well thnx Jay. This answer was somewhat helpful and i figured out the solution.